# 'over short or long' instead of 'sooner or later'?

Tags: expressions

Is it permissible to use 'over short or long' instead of 'sooner or later'?

On the internet and on Google Books I have only found 'over short or long' as 'over short or long time periods'. I would like to know if it is permissible to use it without 'time periods' and whether it would keep its meaning.

Specific example:
Over short or long, the side effects of the inebriant will build up to a point where they will significantly affect one's cognition and emotional state.

Thank you.

Comment: As you have seen, it's appropriate in some contexts.  What context would you like to use it in?

Comment: @Juhasz - I have added a specific example.

Comment: When you say "Is it permissible?" you are asking the wrong question. A better question would be "Does it communicate well?" The answer to that question is "No."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"sooner or later" - is commonly used.

"over short or long time periods" - sounds rather strange, but it might be possible to use it. Maybe you can provide some context, showing how you want to use it?

"over short or long" - in itself, it has no meaning.

You provided the example:

> Over short or long, the side effects of the inebriant will build up to a point where they will significantly affect one's cognition and emotional state.

I don't think it makes much sense. long an short are properties applied to nothing: distance, time...

If you want to say "sooner or later", just use that. It is very clear, very used, no ambiguity.

Comment: I have added a specific example. Thank you for taking the time and looking at my query!

Answer (score 2):

The example sentence doesn't work.  In such a context, *over* is a preposition and like all prepositions, it needs a noun or a pronoun to modify.

Changes happen over *time*
The bridge goes over *the river*
We spoke over *the phone*

*Long* and *short* are adjectives, which also need to modify a noun or a pronoun.

Long or short *time spans*
Long or short *bridges*
Long or short *conversations*

Thus to make such a sentence work, you will need to add a noun which *over* and *long or short* can modify, for instance:

Over long or short time periods...

Lastly, note that the phrase *sooner or later* has an idiomatic meaning (*eventually*) that is distinct from its literal meaning (*either sooner or later*). This idiomatic meaning is not shared by other expressions that have the same literal meaning. That is to say, *sooner or later the side effects build up* does not mean the same thing as *in either a short amount of time or a long amount of time side effects build up*. The latter ("in a short amount of time or a long amount of time") only has a literal meaning: it either takes a short amount of time for the side effects to build up, or a long amount of time for them to build up. The former ("sooner or later") means: eventually - i.e. at some point in time, and it doesn't matter which point - the effects build up.